# how to check the condition in asp.net for string array

Tags: c#, asp.net, conditional-statements

I have to check the condition in asp.net for string array

The conditions is I can either have two values **360__image.jpg** and **image.jpg**.
I have to return the correct value from the condition

1. If the string has 360_image.jpg I have to return only image.jpg and cutting 360_
2. If the string is image.jpg I have to return the same image.jpg

### Code

```
public string splitString(string str)
{
   string[] FileName = str.Split('_');   
   if (FileName[2] != "")
   {
       return FileName[2];
   }
   else
   {
        return FileName[0];
   }
}
```

The problem with above code is I am getting the error

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array
```

Comment: It's not clear. Is 360__ fixed for any "image.jpg"? If so replace it with an empty string. I'm assuming "image" could be a different string every time but not the prefix.

Answer (score 2):

You should check for length before accessing element from the array, that is why you are getting the exception, since split probably resulted in array of two elements.

Not exactly sure about your requirement but I think you can simplify your method as:

```
public string splitString(string str)
{
    if (str.Contains("_")) //or check for 360__
        return str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('_') + 1); 
    else
        return str;
}
```

Comment: I am getting as _image001.png

Comment: @Anish, try `return str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('_') + 1); `

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LastIndexOf`:

```
public string splitString(string str)
{
    return str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('_') + 1);
}
```

Or even use LINQ `Last`:

```
public string splitString(string str)
{
    return str.Split('_').Last();
}
```

Comment: here the string can either have 360_image.jpg or image.jpg so we need the condition to checked for the above answer

Comment: @Anish: you don't need actually, it still works and the code is simpler

Answer (score 0):

Array has 2 elements , means idexes 0 and 1.

But you have taken into your code as `FileName[2]` .

This 2nd index may be wrong thats why error is comming. It may be 1.

Try with:

```
public string splitString(string str)
    {

        string[] FileName = str.Split('_');   

        if (FileName[1] != "")
        {
            return FileName[1];
        }
        else
        {
            return FileName[0];
        }
    }
```